# How can i find a sound intensity by using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

I'm looking for some functions in MATLAB in order to find out some parameters of sound,such az intensity,density,frequency,time and spectral identity.
i know how to use 'audiorecorder' as a function to record the sampled voice,and also 'getaudio', in order to plot it.But i need to realize the parametres of a sampled recorded voice,that i mentioned above.i'd be so thankful if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very vague question, you may want to narrow it down (at first) and to add as much contextual details as you can, it will certainly attract a lot more answers (also as mentionned by Ion, you could post it at http://dsp.stackexchange.com).

**Sound intensity**: microphones usually measures pressure, but you can get the intensity from that quite easily (see [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/548/which-unit-does-the-power-spectrum-of-microphone-output-have)). Your main problem is that microphones are not usually calibrated, this means that you cannot associate an amplitude with a pressure. You can get **sound density** from sound intensity.

**Frequency**: you can get the spectrum of your sound by using the Fast Fourier Transform (see the Matlab function [`fft`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/fft.html)).

As for spectral or time identity, I believe these are psychoacoustics notions, which is not really my area of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but I have played with Matlab a little in the past.

One function I remember was wavread() to input a sound signal into Matlab, which if executed in this form `[Y, FS, NBITS]=WAVREAD("AUDIO.WAV")` would return something like:

```
AUDIO.WAV: 
Fs = 100 kHz 
Bits per sample = 10 
Size = 100000
```

(numbers from the top of my head)

Now about the other things you ask, I'm not really sure. You can expect a better answer from somebody else. I think this question should be moved to Signal Processing SE btw.